# Can I get a fetch function to repeat every few seconds

Tags: javascript, function, fetch, polling

I have a script that uses Fetch to get some values from the sensors on a device, everything works as expected however the values change frequently. I would like the values to update every second, but the only way I have that working now is to add a function that refreshes the browser every second. This is not very elegant.

Is there a way for me to repeat the fetch command in a loop? so that it gets new values every second without having to refresh the browser?

Here is my code:

```
        <script>
        fetch('http://192.168.1.114/rr_Status?type=3')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendDataAsTable(data);
            })            
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });

        function addCell(tr, val) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');

            td.innerHTML = val;

            tr.appendChild(td)
        }

        function addRow(tbl, val_1, val_2) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            addCell(tr, val_1);
            addCell(tr, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp');
            addCell(tr, val_2);
            tbl.appendChild(tr)
        }

        function appendDataAsTable(data) {
            tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

            addRow(tbl, 'Layer Number', data.currentLayer);
            addRow(tbl, 'Fan Speed', data.params.fanPercent[0] + '%');
            addRow(tbl, 'Print Progress', data.fractionPrinted + '%');
            addRow(tbl, 'Current Speed', data.speeds.top + 'mm/s');
            addRow(tbl, 'Hotend Temp', data.temps.current[1] + '°C');
            addRow(tbl, 'Bed Temp', data.temps.current[0] + '°C');
            addRow(tbl, 'Chamber Temp', data.temps.current[2] + '°C');

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tbl" border="0" cellspacing="5" align="left" style="font-weight:bold"></table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to invoke the request every few seconds.

Here, when the document is ready, we are setting up an interval to trigger `fetchStatus` function to be called every 5 seconds.

```
function fetchStatus() {
  fetch('http://192.168.1.114/rr_Status?type=3')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      appendDataAsTable(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // Your document is loaded.
  var fetchInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds.

  // Invoke the request every 5 seconds.
  setInterval(fetchStatus, fetchInterval);
});
```

**Update:** You could make a slight change in your `appendDataAsTable` to replace instead of appending and it should resolve your duplicate rendering issue.

```
function appendDataAsTable(data) {
    tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
    
    // Overwrite the existing HTML with new content received.
    tbl.innerHTML = '';

    addRow(tbl, 'Layer Number', data.currentLayer);
    addRow(tbl, 'Fan Speed', data.params.fanPercent[0] + '%');
    addRow(tbl, 'Print Progress', data.fractionPrinted + '%');
    addRow(tbl, 'Current Speed', data.speeds.top + 'mm/s');
    addRow(tbl, 'Hotend Temp', data.temps.current[1] + '°C');
    addRow(tbl, 'Bed Temp', data.temps.current[0] + '°C');
    addRow(tbl, 'Chamber Temp', data.temps.current[2] + '°C');

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it is very close now to working, however this is duplicating the values every 5 seconds. The values go into the table after 5 seconds, then 5 seconds later the values all duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelMacDonald For that you need to update your existing logic in the `appendDataAsTable(data)` function call. You should check if the data is new or not, if it's not new then don't update it. It should solve your problem.

Or, you may tweak the logic to replace the html instead of appending in the `appendDataAsTable`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @MichaelMacDonald Updated the answer, please check if it helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at that now and let you know ;)